# Opencart: Error No:1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, carousel

I'm developing a carousel extension for opencart that has Item ID, Item Name, Link, Image, Sort Order. The carousel had an issue while saving it will change the item id so I had to modify the code to get fixed ID queryed to the DB, however now I get the 1062 Error.

> Notice: Error: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' Error No: 1062
>   INSERT INTO crousal SET crousal_id = '1', name = 'Baby & Toys', link =
>   '/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=7570', image =
>   'data/carousel/banner2.jpg', sort_order = '0' in
>   /home/user/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 49

Sharing the model/carousel.php editCarousel Function

```
public function editCrousal($crousal_image) {

    $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal WHERE crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_id . "'");

    if (isset($crousal_image['crousal_image'])) {
        foreach ($crousal_image['crousal_image'] as $crousal_image) {

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal SET  crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_id . "', name = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['name']) . "', link = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['link']) . "', image = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$crousal_image['sort_order'] . "'");

            $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        }
    }
}
```

Any advice why I'm getting this error and how to resolve, thank you in advanced.

P.S.: Opencart 1.5.x

Edited: DB Structure & Module info

```
    $this->db->query("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal` (
          `crousal_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          `sort_order` INT(3) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`crousal_id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;");
```

Model File

```
public function addCrousal($crousal_image) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($crousal_image['name']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$crousal_image['sort_order'] . "'");

    $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    if (isset($crousal_image['crousal_image'])) {
        foreach ($crousal_image['crousal_image'] as $crousal_image) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal SET  crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_id . "', link = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['link']) . "', image = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['image']) . "'");

            $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();
        }
    }       
}   

public function editCrousal($crousal_image) {

    $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();

    $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal WHERE crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_id . "'");

    if (isset($crousal_image['crousal_image'])) {
        foreach ($crousal_image['crousal_image'] as $crousal_image) {

            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal SET  crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_id . "', name = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['name']) . "', link = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['link']) . "', image = '" .  $this->db->escape($crousal_image['image']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$crousal_image['sort_order'] . "'");

            $crousal_id = $this->db->getLastId();

        }
    }
}

public function getCrousalImages() {
    $crousal_image_data = array();

    $crousal_image_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal ORDER BY sort_order ASC");

    foreach ($crousal_image_query->rows as $crousal_image) {
        $crousal_image_description_data = array();

        $crousal_image_description_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "mobiapp_crousal WHERE crousal_id = '" . (int)$crousal_image['crousal_id'] . "'");

        $crousal_image_data[] = array(
            'crousal_image'            => $crousal_image,
            'link'                     => $crousal_image['link'],
            'name'                     => $crousal_image['name'],
            'crousal_id'               => $crousal_image['crousal_id'],
            'image'                    => $crousal_image['image'],
            'sort_order'               => $crousal_image['sort_order']
        );
    }

    return $crousal_image_data;
}
```

Comment: Seems like module is not clear. Please provide more info about module and DB table structure

Comment: I've edited the question and added more info about the module and DB structure

Answer (score 1):

I did review for this module. Seems like this module has totally wrong structure. As you can see in method `addCrousal` foreach-statement with insertion to database. But in this insert `carousal_id` not incrementing so in the table will be records with not unique `carousal_id`. So this column can't be PRIMARY. 
I suggest you to rewrite module with two tables "Slides" with relations (has many) "Images". Or you can remove PRIMARY index and operation will pass but it's not true solution.

Comment: If I understood what you said, you're referring to create to databases and have relation between them at this we add classify the carousel items query. I'd like to mention I've copied the default Opencart Banner mod and made my modification and the Carousel is one list and not not multi-list as it comes with Opencart > Banners

Comment: ya, exactly. But hey. Why don't u use default module Carousel instead of banner?

Comment: Because I'm creating an API for mobile app it will use it's own DB and workflow

Comment: alright, take a look to default module Carousel. You can use it to implement yours. Cause it is more related.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, the thing is the default carousel you can create as many carousels as you want however what I'm trying to achieve is different. To explain better the default carousel is linked to banners where you can create unlimited banners e.g. Homepage Banner, SIdebar Banner, etc. And in each banner you can add as much images as you want. My target is to create one carousel only for mobile app and add as much images as you want.

Comment: Ok then you should prototype DB with relations and then build logic